# manipulating general equations with derivatives and anti derivatives

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

Given this relation;

$$z=u\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$$

Is it legal take the antiderivative of both sides with respect to z?

$$\int{z}\partial z=\int{u\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}}\partial z$$

$$\int{z}\partial z=\int{u\partial u}$$

Comment: No, but that cancellation is incorrect.

Comment: no? care to elaborate?